# Node Js server sends 100 response

Tags: node.js, bash, curl

I am uploading a file and executing a script on Node.js server, but the whole process takes a lot of time. Before the process is complete, the server sends response 100 on its own.

So Node.js server does the following things synchronously

1. Upload the files
2. execute the script
3. send 200 response

but while executing the script, the server sends 100.

I have written a while loop in bash script(client) executing the curl statement.

```
curl -i -X POST -F trs_repo=@./TRS.tgz    --max-time 30000  --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null "http://localhost:5055/trs/import"
```

Loop will break only when response is 200.
But when it gets the response 100, it re-executes the curl statement again uploading the file.

Is there any way to make sure Node.js server should not send response 100 on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I used shelljs instead of child_process to execute the bash script in the NodeJs server.
shelljs executes the script, seems to buffer the response.
So when I used shelljs, NodeJs server doesn't send response 100.